# get post bind to id in wp rest api on angular(ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to load each posts from wordpress site using wp-rest-api v2 in ionic(angular) app and then link each post in this list to desired post and page, the problem is the post id are not shown, so if I hover on any of the posts in posts.html I just see link to #/app/posts/ instead of for example #/app/posts/4821(it is the id of sample post)

```
// in App.js I have the route for this pages 

  .state('app.posts', {
    url: '/posts',
    data : { auth : true },
    cache : false,
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/posts.html',
        controller : 'PostsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.postDetails', {
    url: "/postDetail/:postId",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/postDetail.html',
        controller : 'postDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })


  //in controller.js I have the PostsCtrl 
  .controller('postDetailCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $sce) {
    $http.get('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' + $stateParams.postId).then(
      function(returnedData){
        $scope.postDetails = returnedData.data;
        console.log($scope.postDetails);
        $scope.post_title = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.postDetails.title.rendered);
        $scope.post_content = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.postDetails.content.rendered);

      }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
      })

})
```

```html
<!--This will load all the posts in posts.html template -->
<ion-item class="item item-avatar item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="recentPost in recentPosts | filter: searchText" href="#/app/posts/{{post.ID}}">      
 </ion-item>



<!-- this is the postDetails.html, template for each post--> 
   <div class="item item-avatar">
     <div class="text-right item-text-wrap" ng-bind-html="post_title"></div>
      </div>

     <div class="item item-image">
        <img ng-src="{{post_image}}">
     </div>

     <div class="item" dir="rtl">
       <p class="text-right item-text-wrap" ng-bind-html="post_content"></p>
     </div>
```

Comment: Hi have you tried with ng-href .. or if you use ui-router ui-sref="app.postDetails({postId:post.ID})"

Comment: hi, with both ng-href & ui-sref it returns back 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined

Comment: so check if you have the property (maybe is write different) ID in your post entity ..could it maybe is Id or id ??

Comment: well I tried different options like id or Id, but non of them seems to work, 
the code works fine with JSON API plugin (http request route & response is a bit different) but it is not working with wp-rest-api, I think it is something related to this plugin and its api call back, I prefer to use wp-rest-api other wise I would switch to JSON API

Comment: can't you sniff the request with network tab of chrome and get the JSON that is coming back from the API or try to do a request with POSTMAN and check the fields of the JSON?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi it returns back normal array of objects of last 10 recent posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accesing the post item correctly, you are using post.ID instead of recentPost.ID. I think everything else is allright.

It should look like this:

```
<ion-item class="item item-avatar item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="recentPost in recentPosts | filter: searchText" href="#/app/posts/{{recentPost.ID}}">
```

Even better than href is using ui-sref to declare the state and the parameters and let angular build the url. Like this:

```
<ion-item class="item item-avatar item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="recentPost in recentPosts | filter: searchText" ui-sref="app.postDetails({postId: recentPost.ID})">
```

Comment: tnx, that was the problem, for some reason I didn't noticed it at all :), now it taking the post id